# "mcp power or thermal limit exceeded" excessive in messages.log

Tags: power-management, logging

I keep getting `mcp power or thermal limit exceeded` every five seconds while my computer is on, regardless of what it's doing. I found some Intel patches but I don't really know exactly what they do or how to apply them and I also don't want to patch my kernel with these random bits of code from some newsgroup.

Can anyone shed some light on what exactly is going on and what the right fix is in this case? Am I better off just waiting for a kernel patch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a possible solution in [this blog post](http://jordilin.wordpress.com/2010/10/13/ubuntu-maverick-not-a-perfect-10-but-nearly/), to blacklist a particular kernel module.

It works for me.

Edit the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
Add at the end of the file add the text

```
blacklist intel_ips
```

Save the file and restart.

Comment: Seems to work, thanks for the find. I added a plaintext fix in my answer as well, but accepted yours.

Comment: Please add some details from your link.

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this one by [adding a syslog filter](https://bugs.launchpad.net/system76/+bug/636045/comments/51):

```
$ cat /etc/rsyslog/10-mcp-power.conf
:msg,contains,"intel ips 0000:00:1f.6: MCP power or thermal limit exceeded" ~
```

It seems that (at least in my case) this error was not indicative of any dangerous underlying problem, so it seems safe enough just to mute that particular error until the 2.6.37 kernel is officially ready.  Even when it is officially ready, it may introduce new problems that I will then have to troubleshoot; I usually wait a few months before upgrading to a new Ubuntu release.

Info on rsyslog filters: https://serverfault.com/questions/15106/is-there-a-way-to-filter-syslog-entries

Comment: Hmmrmm.. I reread the accepted solution and realized it *doesn't* involve using the natty kernel; there was something on the bug report that suggested doing something along those lines.. it was hard to read.  In any case, barring clear information that the intel_ips module doesn't do anything at all useful, I'm going to stick with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Switched kernels from 2.6.35-22 to 2.6.32-25 to fix a suspend problem and in the process this error disappeared as well.

Just in case the link breaks that xdanx posted, here are the basic steps needed to get rid of this problem:

- Edit file /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
- Add at the end of the file blacklist intel_ips
- Save file and restart.

All credit for the solution goes to Jordi Carillo at http://jordilin.wordpress.com.